# how to merge the values of a list of lists and a list into 1 resulting list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists (`a`) and a list (`b`) which have the same "length" (in this case "4"):

```
a = [
      [1.0, 2.0],
      [1.1, 2.1],
      [1.2, 2.2],
      [1.3, 2.3]
    ]

b = [3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3]
```

I would like to merge the values to obtain the following (`c`):

```
c = [
      [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
      [1.1, 2.1, 3.1],
      [1.2, 2.2, 3.2],
      [1.3, 2.3, 3.3]
    ]
```

currently I'm doing the following to achieve it:

```
c = []
for index, elem in enumerate(a):
    x = [a[index], [b[index]]]  # x assigned here for better readability
    c.append(sum(x, []))
```

my feeling is that there is an elegant way to do this...
*note: the lists are a lot larger, for simplicity I shortened them. they are always(!) of the same length.*

Comment: `[x + [y] for x, y in zip(a, b)]`

Comment: @vaultah: nice! add this as an answer as well. you where the first to respond...

Comment: `c = [a[n]+[b[n]] for n in range(len(b))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python3.5+ use `zip()` within a list comprehension and in-place unpacking:

```
In [7]: [[*j, i] for i, j in zip(b, a)]
Out[7]: [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.1, 2.1, 3.1], [1.2, 2.2, 3.2], [1.3, 2.3, 3.3]]
```

In python 2 :

```
In [8]: [j+[i] for i, j in zip(b, a)]
Out[8]: [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.1, 2.1, 3.1], [1.2, 2.2, 3.2], [1.3, 2.3, 3.3]]
```

Or use `numpy.column_stack` in numpy:

```
In [16]: import numpy as np
In [17]: np.column_stack((a, b))
Out[17]: 
array([[ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ],
       [ 1.1,  2.1,  3.1],
       [ 1.2,  2.2,  3.2],
       [ 1.3,  2.3,  3.3]])
```

Comment: `[*j, i]` works in Python 3.5 and newer. Why not just `j + [i]`, though?

Comment: @vaultah Because it's more elegant and optimized (which are features that OP is looking for)